# Listen to port continuously and dump data to a text file

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu

I have the following code that listens to a call through a socket in a port but I'm missing the function to create a text file and then dump the data into it because later I neet to parse it and show it somewhere else.

```
/*
    Simple udp server
*/
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h> //memset
#include <stdlib.h> //exit(0);
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFLEN 512  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data

void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;

    int s, i, slen = sizeof(si_other) , recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    //create a UDP socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        die("socket");
    }

    // zero out the structure
    memset((char *) &si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));

    si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_me.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //bind socket to port
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&si_me, sizeof(si_me) ) == -1)
    {
        die("bind");
    }

    //keep listening for data
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);

        //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen)) == -1)
        {
            die("recvfrom()");
        }

        //print details of the client/peer and the data received
        printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
        printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);

        //now reply the client with the same data
        if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
        {
            die("sendto()");
        }
    }

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try anything? google - how to write files in c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but just a little bit of research on how to write to a file would have been sufficient.

In your `while(1)` loop, just add the following to your code (see code comments):

```
...

//print details of the client/peer and the data received
printf("Received packet from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(si_other.sin_addr), ntohs(si_other.sin_port));
printf("Data: %s\n" , buf);

/* ----- Begin: write to file ------------------------------------- */
FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/received_data", "a"); // open in append mode
if (NULL == fp) {
    // handle problem here
}

if (fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), recv_len, fp) != recv_len) { // write to file
    // handle problem here
}

if (fclose(fp) != 0) { // flush and close the file descriptor
    // handle problem here
}
/* ----- End: write to file ------------------------------------- */    

//now reply the client with the same data
if (sendto(s, buf, recv_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, slen) == -1)
{
    die("sendto()");
}

...
```

Now everytime you receive data from the client, it gets written(*) to the file `received_data` in `/tmp/`. That means the content of the file will grow until you stop your program. If you want to know how it works and how to handle possible errors, you should check out the links in Striezel's answer.

(*): appended because of the `a` option in `fopen()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functions [fopen()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), [fwrite()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) and (last but not least) [fclose()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose) to solve that problem. They should provide you with the basics you need to write data to a file.